# Div / Block element to appear under a float?

Tags: css, css-float

Given the following example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/DLHGs/1/

Is it possible to have the  `bye` element to render below `hi`, but still remain to the right of the red block? (Rather than on the same line)

To clarify, I dont want to have any uses of `<br />`, and the `float:left` applied to `hi` is not removable, and I dont want to set any other `width` or `height` properties other than those already specified.

Edit:
Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/T4XMq/

Answer (score 1):

[What about this?](http://jsfiddle.net/DLHGs/11/)

I added `float:left` to the div wrapping the "hi" and "bye" and also set "bye" to `clear:left`

```
<div>
    <div style="width:30px; height:300px; background:red; float:left;"></div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <div style="float:left;">hi</div>
        <div style="clear:both;">bye</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far.

The only downside I can see is setting a percentage based width on the `bye` element will constrain it to the width of the floated div on line 3, but I this this is unavoidable.

Comment: Better solution found in my comments.

Comment: whats better about your solution?

Comment: As stated in the first comment, as `bye` in your example is constrained inside a `float:left` it loses knowledge of its container, whereas my example retains knowledge of the container:
http://jsfiddle.net/bWagP/

Answer (score -1):

Well i can see that a normal `clear:both` put bye way under the red box. If you can not make hi `float:right` instead, and use `<div style="clear:right">bye</div>`, a simple linebreak will do in this case:

```
<div style="float:left;">hi</div>
<br />
<div>bye</div>
```

Comment: `I dont want to have any uses of <br />`

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap both elements in a div with `float:left`.

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>bye</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLHGs/8/

Comment: `the float:left applied to hi is not removable`

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
    <div style="width:30px; height:300px; background:red; float:left;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div  style="float:left;">hi</div>
        <div style="">bye</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I dont want to have any uses of <br />`